# MySQL select query, concat and convert to date two fields and compare to time intervals

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two STRING fields in my table which make up the date and time.  I want to concat those fields, convert them into a date so I can get the values between a chosen time.  I think I'm running into a problem with `str_to_date` format inside my query.  Here's what I have in the table

```
theDate        theTime
Mon, Jan 20    7:00 pm
Mon, Jan 20    9:00 pm
Tue, Jan 21    5:00 pm
```

The PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
//trying to set up the same format as the concatenated fields will be
$now = date('D, M j g:i a');
include('..//db_connect.php');
try {
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(theDate, ' ', theTime), '%a, %b %e %l:%i %p') 
        BETWEEN (STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%a, %b %e %l:%i %p') - INTERVAL 4 HOUR AND STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%a, %b %e %l:%i %p') - INTERVAL 10 HOUR)");
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($results);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $stmt."<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
```

What I get is syntax error `near 'HOURS AND STR_TO_DATE('Wed, Jan 21 7:07', '%a, %b %e %l %i') - INTERVAL 10 HOURS' at line 2`.  What's wrong with the query?  Also, is there a way to print out the query itself, to see the concatenated values, to see the formatted values?

Answer (score 1):

One thing is wrong is HOURS. Must be HOUR

Comment: Now I just get an error for  `...server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to pass in the year somewhere... also your are missing the colon `:` on the STR_TO_DATE. It's HOUR in singular
Try like this:

```
// Assuming $now is in the format '2014 Wed, Jan 21 7:07'
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%Y %a, %b %e %l:%i') - INTERVAL 4 HOUR;
```

As per the second part of the question, I think you could do a separated query like this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%Y %a, %b %e %l:%i') - INTERVAL 4 HOUR, STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%a, %b %e %l:%i %p') - INTERVAL 10 HOUR;
```

And then show the results, to see what are the actual values being looked up.

Comment: change the parenthesis of the BETWEEN as this: `BETWEEN (STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%a, %b %e %l %i %p') - INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AND (STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%a, %b %e %l %i %p') - INTERVAL 10 HOUR)`

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(theDate, ' ', theTime), '%a, %b %e %l %i %p') 
        BETWEEN (STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%a, %b %e %l %i %p') - INTERVAL 4 HOURS AND
                 STR_TO_DATE('$now', '%a, %b %e %l %i %p') - INTERVAL 10 HOURS)
```

This doesn't quite look like MySQL syntax.  There are several small problems -- the `hours` and the extra parentheses around the `BETWEEN`, the `BETWEEN` valus in the wrong order.  Perhaps this does what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(theDate, ' ', theTime), '%a, %b %e %l %i %p')
          BETWEEN date_sub(now(), interval 10 hours) AND
                  date_sub(now(), interval 4 hours);
```

You should use native types for dates and times in the database, rather than storing them as strings.  If they are strings, don't give them names like "date" and "time" that suggests that they are something they are not.

Comment: The reason I have it like that is because of the format the values in the table are in.  They're both strings and I want to get them to the proper format.

Comment: Also for the second part of my question...is there a way to echo out the query itself, to see the formatted values as they are being used while searching the table?

Comment: @denikov . . . For the second part, just include the `str_to_date()` expressions in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your error is that you are using `HOURS` instead of `HOUR`, but I suggest a better solution to use `date_sub()` and mysql `now()` methods into something like:

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE myDate BETWEEN date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AND date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR);`

An other sugestion is to save datetime fields as `datetime` and not as `string` less work after.

Comment: I know it would be better to save it that way...it's not how the client structured the database.  I have no control over how the values are being saved